# How can I create an executable file to install a Chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, executable

I am developing a Chrome extension that can autofill forms, and I want to ensure that it can be installed effortlessly via an executable, without the need for any manual manipulation within the Chrome browser.

To achieve this, I am seeking advice on how to make the installer file easily accessible and downloadable from a web page or file-sharing site. Additionally, I want to ensure that users can uninstall the extension quickly and conveniently with just a single click from the browser's extension management page.

the extension is developed using react-typescript

Can you provide any guidance on how to achieve these objectives?

i have tried using drag and drop of the .crx file but i get this error :This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extension web store is the only way a normal user can install extensions from. It just takes 3-4 clicks to install an extension from web store.
For testing purposes you can sart chrome with `--load-extension=<path to unpacked extension>` flag and chrome will automatically install it.
eg

```bash
google-chrome --load-extension=./my-extension
```

According to my knowlege, there is no way to install chrome extension using an executable file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In this case, the extension will only be used internally for testing purposes within a company u suggest any solution

Comment: Chrome web store has way to publish "private"  chrome extensions.